# Счетчик блокировок рекурсивного мьютекса

Tags: c++

Кто подскажет, как в c++ прочитать счетчик блокировок рекурсивного мьютекса?

Comment: Никак, API `recursive_mutex` такой информации не представляет

Comment: Плохо. Спасибо.

Comment: Вы можете создать свою обертку вокруг мьютекса и самостоятельно считать

Comment: Спасибо, я так и сделал.

Comment: Скорее всего, вам это не нужно. Не представляю себе валидного использования количества блокировок. Вы наверняка пытаетесь построить какой-то костыль. Для чего вам значение счётчика?

Comment: в нормально работающей системе - да, нет смысла. Более того, даже вредно (в тот момент, когда получаем состояние счетчика, его значение может поменятся). Но я знаю одно применение - если в системе наблюдаются дедлоки, а использовать valgrin или его аналоги не позволят ось или религия. Но в любом случае, значние подобных счетчиков будет достаточно непоказательным.